# Finding the explicit formula of the inhomogeneous difference

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following inhomogeneous difference equation: 
$$z_{t+1}-z_{t}=1$$

Solving as a homogeneous equation, I get $z_{t}=A(1)^{t}$; however, when solving for the inhomogeneous case, can I try the constant $c,$ since $c-c=0\neq1$?

Just wondering what approach to take- many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use generating functions. Define $Z(u) = \sum_{t \ge 0} z_t u^t$. Your recurrence gives:
$$
\frac{Z(u) - z_0}{u} - Z(u) = \frac{1}{1 - u}
$$
So:
$$
Z(u) = \frac{z_0 - (1 + z_0)u}{(1 - u)^2}
     = \frac{z_0 - 1}{1 - u} + \frac{1}{(1 - u)^2}
$$
Thus:
$$
z_t = z_0 - 1 + \binom{- 2}{n}
    = z_0 - 1 + \binom{n + 1}{1}
    = z_0 + n
$$
Or simpler:
$$
Z(u) = \frac{z_0}{(1 - u)} + \frac{u}{(1 - u)^2}
$$
directly gives the final formula.

Answer (score 0):

To find the general solution to an inhomogeneous recurrence you must first find the general solution to the related homogeneous recurrence (you did that), then find any single solution to the nonhomogeneous one, and add.  $z_t=t$ satisfies the nonhomogeneous recurrence, so the general solution is $z_t=t+A$.